# How do you configure a lookup field's dropdown list preview content?

Tags: page-layout, screen-flow, record, lookup-field

When you have an input control for a lookup field, suggested options are presented in a drop-down menu as you type. Can you change which fields are used in the suggestions and, if so, where is that done?

Ex: In the attached screenshot, we have a custom object called `Rental Rate` that has several fields: `Daily`, `Weekly`, `Monthly`, etc... The drop-down preview is showing the `Name` of the `Rental Rate` and one other field. Can we configure which field is shown? Can we show more than one field?

[image]

Comment: Care to elaborate on the -1 down vote? Happy to be told to RTFM but so far we haven't found the right page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [Search Layout](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.search_edit_layouts.htm&type=5).

You can specify up to 10 fields. However the number of fields visible depends on the context. In a lookup field on a record detail page (like you have), only one additional field is displayed (along with the name of the record).

Go to Setup, Object Manager, Your Object, Search Layouts:

[image]

Comment: Ah, we tried that but didn't see a change because our change was to add additional fields. Since we didn't change the first field, it looked like our change had no effect and concluded this was the wrong place. It's a shame we can't add more than one field to that drop down suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: You could vote up and follow the idea here and see if it ever gets done: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdgBgUAJ/multiple-fields-to-display-on-lookups-in-lightning-experience

Comment: After your initial response, we quickly concluded that a "hidden" formula field that just concatenates all relevant fields would suffice. Sounds like that's the work around for others as well. Thanks for the link.